# BeautifulSoup I scraping no output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scraping price DELTA set from[DELTA](https://www.set.or.th/en/market/product/stock/quote/DELTA/price)

```
#Library
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.set.or.th/en/market/product/stock/quote/DELTA/price'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
price = soup.find('h1',{'class','value text-white mb-0 me-2 lh-1'})
print(price)
```

This Picture is webpage and element
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j76rI.png)
and my coding have resoponse `print(response)`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG0Iz.png)
and I search `value text-white mb-0 me-2 lh-1` not find
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGmpj.png)
I am receiving a None, but I am sure that the url source code contains the elements that I specified. Is there anything in the  [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup)Documentation that I am using?

Comment: What do yo want to crawl could you share a image?

Comment: You are wrong. If you take a look inside `response.text` you'll see there are no elements whose class is `value text-white mb-0 me-2 lh-1`.

Comment: There is no element with class `value text-white mb-0 me-2 lh-1`